# Properties of a set $\{(x,y,z)\in\Bbb R^3\mid x^2+y^2=\arctan(z)\}$ and its image $p(S)$ under the projection $p$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, solution-verification

> Let $S=\{(x,y,z)\in\Bbb R^3\mid x^2+y^2=\arctan(z)\}$ and let $p:\Bbb R^3\to\Bbb R^2,p(x,y,z)= (x,y)$.
>
> Is $S$ closed? Is it compact? What about $p(S)$ and what is $\partial(p(S))$?

**My attempt:**

We can write $S=f^{-1}(\{0\}),$where $f:\Bbb R^3\to\Bbb R, f(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2-\arctan(z).$

$S$ is closed as the preimage of a closed set under a continuous function $f,$ but it is unbounded because $|z|$ can get arbitrarily large and I think it is only $|x|,|y|$ that are bounded by $\frac{\pi}2$ as $|\arctan(z)|<\frac{\pi}2.$

Now, I think $p(S)=\left\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2\mid x^2+y^2<\frac{\pi}2\right\}$ and $p(S)$ is bounded, but not closed as, if we take the sequence $\left(\left(0,\frac{\pi}2-\frac1n,n\right)\right)_n$ in $S,$ we get the sequence $\left(\left(0,\frac{\pi}2-\frac1n\right)\right)_n$ in $p(S)$ converging to $\left(0,\frac{\pi}2\right)\color{red}{\notin p(S)}$ because, if $(x,y,z)\in S,$ then $|y|<\frac{\pi}2.$ Therefore, I think $p(S)$ is not compact.

If my conclusion $p(S)$ is right, then $\partial (p(S))=\left\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2\mid x^2+y^2=\frac{\pi}2\right\}$ because $\begin{aligned}\overline{p(S)}&=\operatorname{Int}(p(S))\cup\partial(p(S))\\\implies\partial (p(S))&=\overline{p(S)}\setminus\operatorname{Int}(p(S))\\&=\overline{p(S)}\setminus p(S)\\&=\left\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2\mid x^2+y^2\le \frac{\pi}2\right\}\setminus\left\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2\mid x^2+y^2<\frac{\pi}2\right\}\end{aligned}$

Or, we could take an arbitrary point $T=\frac\pi2(\cos(\theta),\sin(\theta)),\theta\in[0,2\pi)$ on the circle and construct two sequences $$a_n=\left(\frac\pi2-\frac1n\right)(\cos(\theta),\sin(\theta))\quad\text{in }p(S)\\\text{and}\\b_n=\left(\frac\pi2+\frac1n\right)(\cos(\theta),\sin(\theta))\quad\text{in }\Bbb R^2\setminus p(S)$$ to argue that, $\forall\varepsilon>0$ the open ball $B(T,\varepsilon)$ contains some points both from $p(S)$ and $\Bbb R^2\setminus p(S)$.

Is my answer valid? If not, how should I improve it?

Comment: Your second argument about $\partial(p(S))$ only shows one inclusion (if $T$ is in the circle then $T$ in the boundary)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your arguments are correct. In my opinion the part concerning $p(S)$ is too complicated. You correctly show that $p(S)$ is the open disk $B(0,r) = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 \mid x^2 + y^2 < r^2\}$ with center $0$ and radius $r = \sqrt{\pi/2}$. It is well-known that an open disk $B(0,r)$ is not closed and that its topological boundary is the circle $S(0,r) = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 \mid x^2 + y^2 = r^2\}$ with center $0$ and radius $r$.

If you really want to expicitly prove these facts, you can do it as follows:

1. Observe that $B(0,r)$ is an open subset of $\mathbb R^2$.
2. Observe that $D(0,r) =  \{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 \mid x^2 + y^2 \le r^2\}$ is closed subset of $\mathbb R^2$.
3. Observe that $S(0,r)$ is contained in the closure of $B(0,r)$: Given $z \in S(0,r)$, the points $z_n = (1-1/n)z$ lie in $B(0,r)$ and $z_n \to z$.
4. Conclude that the closure of $B(0,r)$ is $D(0,r)$ and that hence $\partial B(0,r) = S(0,r)$.